ES6 inner join equivalent
Using the sample data from here, I'm attempting to write JS code (to the ES6 standard) that is equivalent to an SQL inner join.  The solution below works fine, but it seems rather long.  Is there a more concise approach?


const employees = [
    {name: 'Alice', department_id: 12},
    {name: 'Bob', department_id: 13},
    {name: 'Chris', department_id: 13},
    {name: 'Dan', department_id: 14},
    {name: 'Eve', department_id: null}
];

const departments = [
    {department_id: 12, name: 'Sales'},
    {department_id: 13, name: 'Marketing'},
    {department_id: 14, name: 'Engineering'},
    {department_id: 15, name: 'Accounting'},
    {department_id: 16, name: 'Operations'}
];

const ij1 = employees.flatMap(employee =>
    departments.map(department => {
        if (employee.department_id == department.department_id) {
            return {
                employee_name: employee.name,
                employee_department_id: employee.department_id,
                department_id: department.department_id,
                department_name: department.name
            }
        }
    }).filter(Boolean)
);

console.log(ij1);




Why do you need to do this? I can't find it, but there's an old blog post along the lines of "Are you doing SQL in the browser? Don't." Generally, the backend should be doing these operations on the database, so it'd be good to provide some context about why you're doing this, or how often this "function" will be called. If you're doing it more than once, you probably want objects keyed by id for faster lookups. In any case, there's not much code to review here--I'm surprised you think this is long, because it's just a few lines of code. There are probably bigger issues than length here.

The data is coming from an external API.

Thanks, but can you provide more details? Which API? How large are the structures? How often are you doing joins? Why not make those requests from a proxy API and cache them server side? Most third-party APIs block cross origin requests, and you'd want to keep your key safe on the server anyway. Like I said, I can maybe trim off a line of code here, but without understanding the full use case, it's probably not going to do you much good without seeing the whole forest from this one tree.

Current use case - API is to access the company's ERP system data (this ERP system is a third party application), structure sizes vary depending on endpoint.  Data from API is being consumed in a Vue app without a database.

OK, thanks. How often are you running this join? One time or multiple? Are the sizes large enough that performance is a concern, or are these mostly small (less than a couple hundred items)?

Frequency - once, when Vue component is called.  Size varies depending on endpoint - sometimes a few items, sometimes 10,000+ items.

Use a Map
Existing answers are using Object.groupBy to create a map of departments grouped by id.
This is inappropriate as there is only a one to one relationship between department id and departments. Object.groupBy creates groups using arrays to hold members of each group. One to many.
Using a more appropriate Map to get departments by id will simplify the code a little as there is no need to do the additional array indexing when locating a department.
Don't duplicate data
Nor can I see why you duplicate the department_id as employee_department_id which is redundant information.


const employees = [{name: 'Alice', department_id: 12}, {name: 'Bob', department_id: 13}, {name: 'Chris', department_id: 13}, {name: 'Dan', department_id: 14}, {name: 'Eve', department_id: null}];
const departments = [{department_id: 12, name: 'Sales'}, {department_id: 13, name: 'Marketing'}, {department_id: 14, name: 'Engineering'}, {department_id: 15, name: 'Accounting'}, {department_id: 16, name: 'Operations'}];

console.log(innerJoinEmpDep(departments, employees));

function innerJoinEmpDep(deps, emps) {
    const depsById = new Map(deps.map(dep=> ([dep.department_id, dep])));
    const innerJoin = [];
    for (const emp of emps) {
        const dep = depsById.get(emp.department_id);
        if (dep) {
            innerJoin.push({
                employ: emp.name, 
                department: dep.name,
                depId: dep.department_id
            });
        }
    }
    return innerJoin;
}




Agreed on the data duplication point.  The duplication here was a sanity check to make sure things were working as expected.

Great answer, but new Map(deps.map(dep=> ([dep.department_id, dep]))) is two passes, and allocates an array for every element that gets thrown away to build the map. groupBy reads nicely, is succinct and is one-pass, with per-element allocation overhead (hence the reduce option I provided, which is one pass and has no allocation overhead), and the downside of having to use [0], but I provided a couple of alternatives that are 1 to 1. Using a traditional loop and push rather than reduce is probably a good call; less clever than reduce.

Is a for...of loop preferable to .forEach()?  If so, why?

for ... of is generally better because it reads more nicely and looks more native--less parentheses, no function call overhead, cleaner syntax (more imperative, less functional). I generally only use .forEach if it's at the end of a chain or if I need an index.

Sometimes I like to return early. While you can do it with a forEach, its easier to do that with a for ... of. Personal opinion mostly, as probably for other answers as well. There's no better, it's situational.

@ggorlen depsById as a Map should be the form of the departments records (rather than an array), I would not count m Not O(m+n) just O(n). Another benefit using a for loop is that the function can easily be converted to a generator. This lets a long blocking task be divided into smaller chunks, thus not blocking the page and giving the UI execution time

It's probable that m (departments) is small, in which case it likely doesn't matter which approach we choose, and this one is certainly strong. Regarding loops: yeah, for...of can be returned and breaked, plays nicely with generators, and also works with async/await, which forEach does not.

Based on your follow up comments, you're only running this once when the app loads, but you may have 10k+ items, so performance is a concern. Your current algorithm is quadratic and uses unnecessary passes.
Generally, you want to filter first, then map. The reason is that mapping first results in processing a bunch of items you may well be throwing away in the filter step.
.filter(Boolean) at the end of a chain is an antipattern. Generally, it's a lazy way to remove falsey values that could have been more properly handled earlier in the chain. Specifically, rewrite:
departments.map(department => {
    if (employee.department_id == department.department_id) {
        return {
            employee_name: employee.name,
            employee_department_id: employee.department_id,
            department_id: department.department_id,
            department_name: department.name
        }
    }
}).filter(Boolean)

as:
departments
  .filter(department =>
    employee.department_id === department.department_id
  )
  .map(department => ({
    employee_name: employee.name,
    employee_department_id: employee.department_id,
    department_id: department.department_id,
    department_name: department.name
  });

This is more performant and idiomatic: the filtering does only filtering, and the mapping only does mapping, rather than smushing both into map and then using filter later to remove undefined elements.
Similarly, using flatMap to filter by smushing empty arrays together involves an unnecessary inner array allocation for every item, regardless of whether the array is empty or not. This is OK for small pieces of data, but it's a lot of unnecessary overhead on larger datasets and isn't particularly easy to read anyway. Generally avoid flatMap for filtering and use it for flattening.
Even though you're only doing this operation once, I'd still use a lookup table to avoid repeated loops over the inner array:


const employees = [
  {name: 'Alice', department_id: 12},
  {name: 'Bob', department_id: 13},
  {name: 'Chris', department_id: 13},
  {name: 'Dan', department_id: 14},
  {name: 'Eve', department_id: null}
];

const departments = [
  {department_id: 12, name: 'Sales'},
  {department_id: 13, name: 'Marketing'},
  {department_id: 14, name: 'Engineering'},
  {department_id: 15, name: 'Accounting'},
  {department_id: 16, name: 'Operations'}
];

const departmentsById = Object.groupBy(
  departments,
  e => e.department_id
);

const ij1 = employees.reduce((a, e) => {
  const d = departmentsById[e.department_id];

  if (d) {
    a.push({
      employee_name: e.name,
      employee_department_id: e.department_id,
      department_id: d[0].department_id,
      department_name: d[0].name,
    });
  }

  return a;
}, []);

console.log(departmentsById);
console.log(ij1);



Assuming O(1) lookups, the time complexity is now O(n + m) rather than O(nm).
Note that I've avoided filter and map entirely in favor of a single reduce. I prefer avoiding reduce in favor of a filter and map pair, but in this case, reduce allows us to avoid a second pass over the data, so it's a worthwhile performance tradeoff.
If departments is guaranteed to be pretty small, say, 10 or 20 items, then there may be no reason to use the lookup table and a nested loop and separating reduce into separate map and filter calls can be acceptable from a performance standpoint.
I'll keep _ in the variable names because that's probably how your API is returning the data, but keep in mind this isn't standard JS style. Normalize to camelCase rather than snake_case as soon as possible. ij1 is also a poor variable name--1 looks like l and I, and i and j are usually used for indexes, but I assume you picked this due to some domain-specific reason that makes sense from the context. Nonetheless, there should be another option generally comprehensible to anyone.
Always use ===, never ==, which performs surprising type coercion that can lead to subtle, silent bugs.
If you're in an environment that doesn't have Object.groupBy, you can use reduce:
const departmentsById = departments.reduce((a, e) => {
  a[e.department_id] = e;
  return a;
}, {});

Also possible (cleaner, but requires two passes and likely higher heap allocation overhead):
const departmentsById = Object.fromEntries(
  departments.map(e => [e.department_id, e])
);

In both cases, you'll need to make a small modification later in the code. Instead of d[0].department_id, use d.department_id, since groupBy makes array values (but here, we're guaranteed to have unique ids, so the arrays are superfluous).
Speaking of which, groupBy will incur some allocation overhead for those unnecessary arrays. I'd expect reduce to be fastest, but this is just a hunch and I haven't benchmarked anything. It probably doesn't matter a whole lot since it's back in linear time complexity territory either way, and departments is probably on the small side, but worth keeping in mind.

I fully endorse the approach in this answer, avoiding the duplicate ID and using a loop rather than a reduce. The Map suggested there is a perfectly reasonable alternative to plain objects or groupBy as well.

Can you add console.log(departmentsById); to make its result visible in the code snippet?  I seem to be having some difficulty with that part.

Done. What difficulty are you having? Maybe I can help. Object.groupBy is fairly new, so you may want to use a traditional reduce to group there. One downside of groupBy is that the values are arrays, assuming multiple things will be grouped together, but in this case it's guaranteed to be one item since the ids are unique, so you'll always need to use d[0] to access the first item in each grouping.

Thanks.  I was doing some basic testing using Node to run the JS and Object.groupBy() wouldn't work.  I have used this pattern in the past to create lookups: const departmentLookup = Object.assign({}, ...departments.map(department => ({ [department.department_id]: department }))); and, using this as the lookup source, did some minor refactoring of your original code in my test code to get it to work.  However, maybe a .reduce() approach to create the lookup is better/more efficient than Object.assign()...?

See the update. I've added alternate approaches that don't use groupBy.

An alternative approach (inspired by this thread), for which some feedback would be appreciated, is as follows.  One bonus I see to this object merging approach is it's possible to create a left outer join equivalent or an inner join equivalent with just 1 line of code that's different.


// original data
const employees = [
    {name: 'Alice', department_id: 12},
    {name: 'Bob', department_id: 13},
    {name: 'Chris', department_id: 13},
    {name: 'Dan', department_id: 14},
    {name: 'Eve', department_id: null}
];

const departments = [
    {department_id: 12, name: 'Sales'},
    {department_id: 13, name: 'Marketing'},
    {department_id: 14, name: 'Engineering'},
    {department_id: 15, name: 'Accounting'},
    {department_id: 16, name: 'Operations'}
];

// prepare source data for use -
// 1. renaming keys within objects before merging preserves all key/value pairs in final result
// 2. putting all key names in "left" object displays them for all resultant objects
const employees2 = employees.map(employee => ({
    employee_name: employee.name,
    employee_department_id: employee.department_id,
    department_id: null,
    department_name: null
 }));

const departments2 = departments.map(department => ({
    department_id: department.department_id,
    department_name: department.name
}));

// left outer join equivalent
const loj5 = employees2
    .map(employee => Object.assign({}, employee, departments2.find(department => department.department_id == employee.employee_department_id)));

// inner join equivalent
const ij5 = employees2
    .filter(employee => employee.employee_department_id != null)
    .map(employee => Object.assign({}, employee, departments2.find(department => department.department_id == employee.employee_department_id)));

console.log('left outer join equivalent\r\n', loj5, '\r\nLength:', loj5.length);
console.log('inner join equivalent\r\n', ij5, '\r\nLength:', ij5.length);




It's worth mentioning that this is still quadratic, maybe OK if departments is guaranteed to be small, but overhead-heavy. I'm surprised in benchmarks all the time, though.

You told us there are 1e4 employees in 1e4 departments,
in some unspecified distribution,
presumably pretty sparse with lots of un-staffed departments.

The solution below works fine,

Really?!?

but it seems rather long. Is there a more concise approach?

Yeah, 1e8 seems on the "long" side.
An M × N cartesian cross product gets ugly fast
when your inputs get big.

For the input sizes you contemplate, this approach makes little sense.
Instead, read in all the employees, and devote \$O(M \log M)\$ effort
to sort them by department_id.
Next read all departments and sort them, with \$O(N \log N)\$ effort.
Finally exploit
2-way merge
to emit all relevant emp+dept result objects.
driving table
If, as seems likely, there's more employees than departments,
it would make more sense to first read in all departments.
And sort them.
(If you can obtain "number of employees in department" at the same
time, containing many zeros, then use that to filter out
useless departments from the get go.)
Now scan across all employees in whatever random order they appear,
doing binary search to find matching department,
emitting emp+dept records as appropriate.
This has a smaller memory footprint,
given that we only sorted the smaller table.
(\$M > N\$)
Notice that \$M × O(\log N) + O(N \log N) < O(M \log M) + O(N \log N)\$
under that condition.
